# Helm Chart Definitions for Multi Cluster Codebase

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a project that contains the deployment descriptor files for Kubernetes. This project has a folder structure that looks like this:

```
> project-deployment
>  - base
>  - dev
>  - production
```

Inside the base folder, I have the kubernetes deployment files (deployment, service, namespaces etc.,). In the dev and production folder, I have kustomization.yaml that composes everything from the base folder. So far so good. I now want to introduce helm into this so that I can manage my releases much better. My question now is how do I go about structuring my folder structure?

Should I move everything (base, dev and production) folder into templates and just have one Charts.yaml and values.yaml? Any thoughts?

Comment: Here is the project as a reference: https://github.com/joesan/plant-simulator-deployment/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration values that you push into your charts should be separate between environments. Build simple extendable charts that can have overrides per environment.
For example, a good workflow would have different value files per environment with specific differences in configuration:

```
~/myapp
└── config
├── production.yml
└── staging.yml
```

There are tools that can help you manage that particular use case. For example, consider using [orca](https://github.com/nuvo/orca):

> What Orca does best is manage environments. An Environment is a
> Kubernetes namespace with a set of Helm charts installed on it. There
> are a few use cases you will probably find useful right off the bat.

There are also some [examples](https://github.com/nuvo/orca/tree/master/docs/examples) provided with it.

I also recommend going through the official [The Chart Best Practices Guide](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_best_practices/).

Comment: @sparkr Have you managed to make it work?

Comment: @Wiktor Yes I made it to work. Have a look at my repo! I now have conftest, kustomize and helm all working together doing a full blown CI for my k8s resources! Cool stuff!